# Populate Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to make a "movie ranking" for school.
The language is C#

I want to use a dictionary, where

- Key = Movie Name
- Value = Assigned stars.

Put it inside a loop and ask for 5 inputs. The code looks something like this:

```cs
// Create a dictionary with string key and Int16 value pair  
Dictionary<string, Int16> Ranking = new Dictionary<string, Int16>();
            
for (int i = 1; i < 6; I++)
{
    string MovieName = txbPelicula.Text;
    Int16 Stars = Convert.ToInt16(txbPuntuacion.Text);
    Ranking.Add(MovieName, Stars);

    MessageBox.Show("la lista de películas es " + Ranking);              

}
```

Once I exit the loop, sort the Dictionary and Print it ordered by the amount of stars.

Am I well headed?
Some of my classmates used a List, but I don´t understand how will they join Movie Name with it´s Stars.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to use lists then you could have 2 lists: one to store the keys and one to store the values. Then you can index both of them since you would know both key value pairs will have the same indexs

Comment: Your code will add the same movie and rating to the dictionary 5 times. You need to think through how a user will enter the data and build your dictionary based on that.

Comment: Don't use `Convert.ToInt16`. Use `Int16.TryParse` instead - otherwise your program may crash if someone enters a non-numeric value and to let your program differentiate between `0` and invalid-input.

Comment: You also need to check that the specified movie-name isn't already in the dictionary, otherwise duplicate keys in the `.Add` call will cause a crash.

Comment: Also use a case-insensitive string-comparison in the `Dictionary` constructor-call, otherwise you'll have duplicates for "Saving Private Ryan" and "saving private ryan", for example - however you'll need to build a proper denormalizer so that "saving pvt ryan" or "saving private ryan (1998)" also refer to the same entry.

Comment: Great, thanks.
I might try the lists then.

I thought that the value inside the given variable would be stored each time the loop iterates

Comment: @Alex A better alternative would be to use a list of tuples: List<Tuple<string, int>>

Comment: Since the same textbox is used to pickup data in a loop, the user is not given any opportunity to input more than one movie. What you need to do is to add a button that once pressed adds a movie ranking into your list or dictionary. Another button can be used to order the list by star descending. Does your homework require you to implement the sort functionality or can you use the builtin capability in C#?

Comment: @roby - What do you mean by "I thought that the value inside the given variable would be stored each time the loop iterates"?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a bit too advanced.
I don't know the difference between implementing the sort functionality and the builtin one. I'll have to google that. Or all of the above.

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean that passing the name of the variable in each loop, would assign the value contained in it for either the Key or the Value. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @roby - You can't pass the "name" of a variable. You can pass a variable. And you don't "assign the value contained in it for either the Key or the Value". You have two variables, one for the key and the other for the value, but neither of those variables change in your loop. You are repeatedly assigning the same value to the same key in the dictionary.

Comment: If I would have to code in Python I'd do this:
'''
ranking = {}

for i in range(1, 4):
    pelicula = input("Pelicula: ")
    estrellas = int(input("Estrellas: "))
    ranking.update( {pelicula : estrellas} )

print('\n\n\nEl ranking de Peor a mejor es: \n')    
for key, value in sorted(ranking.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print(key, ' : ', value)
'''

I thought I could use a similar structure in C#

Comment: If I would have to code in Python I'd do this:
```
ranking = {}

for i in range(1, 4):
    movie = input("Movie Name: ")
    stars = int(input("How many Stars: "))
    ranking.update( {movie : stars} )

print('\n\n\nThe list from Worst to Best movie is: \n')    
for key, value in sorted(ranking.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

I thought I could use a similar structure in C#

Comment: @roby - Is this a Windows Forms app? If so how are you expecting the user to enter the data?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list of Movie [classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) or [structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct). The Movie class needs to contain the name of the movie, and its rating.

```
class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public Movie(string name, int rating)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rating = rating;
    }
}
```

```
Movie movie = new Movie("Bad movie", 1);
var name = movie.Name;
var rating = movie.Rating;
```

```
var movies = new List<Movie>();

//...

foreach (Movie movie in movies.OrderBy(movie => movie.Rating))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", movie.Name, movie.Rating);
}
```

Comment: Please read the question and see what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's exactly what I did. "Am I well headed? Some of my classmates used a List, but I don´t understand how will they join Movie Name with it´s Stars." I gave them a solution that works with lists, which they didn't know how the classmates would make work, and by that suggested an alternative approach to the one the OP thought was the best.

Comment: @Enigmativity [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357051)

Comment: I really feel that this question is about taking user input from a (presumably) Windows Forms app and display the results in some form of list. You've jumped over to a Console app and ignored the user input. A dictionary would have worked just fine for the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've jumped over to a Console App? How? The main part of my answer is the use of a list of classes instead of a dictionary. Because I use `Console.WriteLine` instead of `MessageBox.Show(_:)`? Even though the OP is working in a Windows Forms environment, there's no requirement for that in the question, and my solution is not exclusive to console apps. There's neither any request for Windows Forms code.

Comment: @Enigmativity Please don’t downvote because I provide an answer to the underlying problem instead. My answer still answers that issue. You’ve not given me any reasons why my answer is not answering this XY problem, and you’ve neither stated it’s bad, its quality is bad, or that it’s incorrect for both X and Y.

Comment: That the question is more about the user input than the Dictionary or a List. The OP is a beginner and he wants to know if his overall approach is correct. Just changing to a list of custom objects will not make his code work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218615/discussion-between-andreas-and-enigmativity).